# Testing python smtp email service

Tags: python, email, amazon-ec2, smtplib

So I wrote a simple email service using smtplib to send welcome emails when user first logs in. I was wondering what's the best way to test out my code.

```
def send_email(nickname, email):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

    config = read_config_file(MAIL_CONFIG_PATH)
    sen = config.get('gmail_credentials', 'email')
    pwd = config.get('gmail_credentials', 'password')

    server = None
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(sen, pwd)
        server.sendmail(sen, [email], msg.as_string())
        return 'Sent!'

    finally:
        if server:
        server.quit()
```

I found out that you can use a fake smtp server:

```
sudo python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25
```

But I am still not sure how I should implement something like this into my code. How do I change my API so that it runs the SMTP server during testing and connects to the GMAIL server for the actual calls? And are there init scripts which will run the SMTP server on our servers (this will be deployed on AWS EC2).

Answer (score 3):

To anyone who comes across this old ticket with the same issue, I wanted to write integration tests with the standard library, so the above solutions didn't work for me. Setting up a debugging server locally within the unit testing code was also a bit tricky, and allegedly doesn't support starttls. In the end I went with this;

```
import smtplib
from unittest import TestCase

class TestSMTP(TestCase)

    ...
    setup etc.

    def test_smtp_connection(self):
        # connect to actual host on actual port
        smtp = smtp.SMTP(host, port)
        smtp.starttls()

        # check we have an open socket
        self.assertIsNotNone(smtp.sock)

        # run a no-operation, which is basically a server-side pass-through
        self.assertEqual(smtp.noop(), (250, '2.0.0 OK'))

        # assert disconnected
        self.assertEqual(smtp.quit(), (221, '2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel'))
        self.assertIsNone(smtp.sock)
```

Note, these are integration tests, which is all you need to do to verify your email server is working. Everything else can be done by mocking `smtp.SMTP` and capturing whatever's passed into `sendmail` and verifying the contents there. You're not unit testing smtp, you're unit testing your application.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: I worked on the product in question, please note this answer may contain bias.**

I co-founded a hosted service called [Mailosaur](https://mailosaur.com), that allows developers (us included) to test this kind of process in a real-world setting (i.e. over the net, using SMTP).

You get an SMTP endpoint (also unlimited test email addresses, but you're using SMTP so shouldn't need this).

The service then converts emails into a [JSON representation](https://mailosaur.com/api/), which you can get via an HTTP API.

To make the querying a little easier use can use client bindings (available for [Java](https://github.com/mailosaurapp/mailosaur-java), .NET and Ruby), but you can use regular curl or any other HTTP client (or get in touch and we'd be happy to put together a Python client).

The final test process would be:-

1. Send email via SMTP to `smtp.mailosaur.in` (no need to change to from/to addresses)
2. Query the API:

   ```
   curl https://mailosaur.com/v2/emails?mailbox={mailbox}&key={api_key}
   ```
3. Do your regular asserts (pseudo code):

   ```
   assert.equal(3, email.attachments.length, 'Expected 3 attachments');
   assert.contains('https://verify-url', email.html.links, 'Expected link to verification url');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: applications that send email, and I want to check that they do so correctly *without* spamming a bunch of real people with email of various forms of incompletenese.

I use **PostHoc** which receives email using SMTP, but then simply displays the email that was sent in a web browser.

It is on GitHub at:  https://github.com/agilepro/posthoc

Here is a blog post that describes it: https://agiletribe.purplehillsbooks.com/2017/07/24/posthoc-testing-apps-that-send-email/

The reason I don't run a real SMTP server is that those servers are designed to actually find the and deliver the mail to the recipients.  I want to test the application with real email address and real mailing lists.  I want to see that the real situation can be handled, and I want to verify that each email sent looks the way it should.  I want all this, but I want to be *sure* that no email is ever actually delivered.

For years I had a switch in the application that redirected email to a different address, and I could see the email there.  But this is still problematic since the application is running in a different mode than it will in production.  With PostHoc the application runs *exactly* as it will in production, and I still can safely see all the email sent.

**PostHoc** requires TomCat to run it, but nothing else.

I like the way it automatically deletes all the old messages after 5 days.  I have never needed to see one of these emails after 5 days, and so I just never need to do any clean up around it.